# RTSPPlay Multiple Frames on Screen

Tags: ios, rtsp

I am trying to develop an iOS application that is able to stream rtsp feed. Thanks to the RTSPPlay sample program, I was able to do that.
I want to customise the app in such a way that not just a single frame is displayed on the screen- i wish to have 2 or more frames displayed all at the same time streaming feeds from different cameras.

I am not exposed so much to iOS programming as I am more experienced with Android programming. So I am a bit clueless on how I can achieve my desired customisation.

What I've tried is I just created multiple instances of FrameExtractor, UIImageView to represent the multiple frames. I did it like this:

```
self.video2 = [[FrameExtractor alloc] initWithVideo:@"<rtsp feed 2>"];

self.video2.cgimageDelegate = self;

video2.outputWidth = 320;

video2.outputHeight = 240;

[video2 setupCgimageSession];

NSLog(@"video2 duration: %f",video2.duration);

NSLog(@"video2 size: %d x %d", video2.sourceWidth, video2.sourceHeight);
```

and inside (void)didOutputCGImageBuffer:(NSTimer *)timer, i also did this:

```
[video2 stepFrame];

imageView2.image = video2.currentImage;
```

however, all of the frames stream the same feed, which is the rtsp feed i indicated in my last instance of FrameExtractor.

What could be the proper approach for this?

Comment: the fact that this is uses a delegate would keep you from being able to create multiple streams. You need to use another framework to accomplish that.

Comment: multi-stream example will be on our git within the next 10 days, you can try that

Comment: hi @MichelleCannon, thanks for the great news. Looking forward to that multi-stream example

Answer (score 0):

Refer this https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer

It is a working sample of the same concept your are using. Then create multiple instance of the RTSPPlayer with different RTSPStreams and you will be able to view them.